# Handling exceptions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Please can you review my standard exception handler for Python 3.x. It is located under the `# +=+=` line. The code above the line is to create an exception and so the code is code complete and runs standalone.

The code is just a standard exception formatter, so users are presented with easier to read messages rather than stack traces. This is a common idiom in many Python projects. But many / all don't format to the extent I have.

I have searched a lot, but I [can't find anything better](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53427/php-error-exception-handling-library-python-would-be-nice-too). I expected to find something on GitHub, but was unfruitful. If you find a way to improve this, please post it here so that I and others will know.

```
import inspect
import os
import sys
import traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        x = 42/0

    # +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e: # Ctrl-C
        raise e
    except SystemExit as e: # sys.exit()
        raise e
    except Exception as e :
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        scriptName = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        functionName = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
        print('=======================================================================================================')
        print('Unhandled exception: ', exc_type, scriptName, 'at line', exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        print('                      in function', functionName)
        print('                     ', str(e))

        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Having said that, I think you got a nice idea going and I'm totally incorporating your idea into my current project.

Comment: Please let me know if you ever make improvements, no mater how tiny. For instance, my PHP project email me on exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Rather than using `as e` then `raise e` you can just omit `e`.

   > ```py
   > except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
   >     raise e
   > ```

   ```py
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       raise
   ```
2. Rather than specifying an except block for `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` you can just specify them in the same `except` by passing a tuple.

   > ```py
   > except KeyboardInterrupt:
   >     raise
   > except SystemExit:
   >     raise
   > ```

   ```py
   except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
       raise
   ```
3. Both `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` are not subclasses of `Exception` so you do not need to handle them. The exceptions will propagate like normal.

   You may want to familiarize yourself with the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).
4. You can get all the information that `sys.exc_info()` gives from `e`.

   > ```py
   > exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
   > ```

   ```py
   exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = type(e), e, e.__traceback__
   ```
5. You can get the current frame from `exc_tb` rather than `inspect.currentframe()`. This makes the code more portable if you ever decide to move the code into a function to format tracebacks.

   > ```py
   > frame = inspect.currentframe()
   > ```

   ```py
   frame = exc_tb.tb_frame
   ```
6. Please follow PEP 8 and name variables with `snake_case`. It is very easy to see the code you've taken from the Python docs and the code you've written yourself / taken from somewhere else.
7. If you're going to hard code the `==` at least use `*` to build it the size you want.

   > ```
   > print('=======================================================================================================')
   > ```

   ```
   print('=' * 103)
   ```
8. Better yet just print to the size of the terminal.

   ```
   print('=' * os.get_terminal_size().columns)
   ```
9. I would prefer to use f-strings if available.

   > ```py
   > print('Unhandled exception: ', exc_type, script_name, 'at line', exc_tb.tb_lineno)
   > ```

   ```py
   print(f'Unhandled exception:  {exc_type} {script_name} at line {exc_tb.tb_lineno}')
   ```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        x = 42/0
    except Exception as e:
        exc_tb = e.__traceback__
        script_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        function_name = exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
        print('=' * os.get_terminal_size().columns)
        print(f'Unhandled exception:  {type(e)} {script_name} at line {exc_tb.tb_lineno}')
        print(f'                      in function {function_name}')
        print(f'                      {e}')

        traceback.print_exc()
        raise SystemExit(1)
```

Comment: Wow! Some incredible feedback. I can see that I still have a lot to learn. I will hold off awarding the answer for a day or two, although I doubt that there will be a better answer. I still can't figure out why there isn't something like this on GitHub, maybe with the option to email the developer on exception (something for me to add. Maybe I will also add `pprint.pprint(locals())` and `pprint.pprint(globals())`).

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I would assume one of the following is why ① most authors assume the user will know how to read Python trackbacks ② many authors don't know how to format tracebacks - how many people know `__traceback__` even exists never-mind `tb_frame`? ③ The application uses `logging` rather than exceptions to inform the user of errors and function state. ⏣ I'd assume a combination of ①&② leave many projects with simple `except` blocks if anything. Then because ③ is much easier and expressive than ② it's just not worth it to most people. That said pytest has something similar.

Comment: Well, as you can guess, I am self-taught, in a rather piecemeal, patchwork fashion :-)  I will look into [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and see how [PyTest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/) handles things.  Thanks again for some great feedback